# c# numpad acts like keyboard

Tags: c#, forms, textbox, keypress, numpad

I am trying to come up with a code that will, depending on what key is pressed in a read-only text box, add or subtract 1 to other text boxes.  My problem is I need to differentiate the numpad #(0-9) from the #s above the qwerty keyboard. When I use the code below with NumLock ON the numpad number acts exactly like the other number(subtracts 1). When NumLock is OFF it does nothing. I want it to add 1 when I press a numpad # and subtract 1 when I press a non-numpad #. I've tried Google-ing the answer but I couldn't come up with anything.

Thanks for any help.

```
void txtTotal_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)//when a key is pressed total text box, depending on key add or subtract 1 to another test box (txtTotal is set to read only)
    {


switch (e.KeyChar)
        {                
            case (char)96://numpad 0
                addNRBC();
                break;
      case (char)48://keyboard 0
                subtractNRBC();
                break;
    }

}


 public void addNRBC()
    {
        num1 = Convert.ToInt32(txtNRBC.Text);
        txtNRBC.Text = Convert.ToString(num1 + 1);//adds 1 to NRBCs field
        Total();
    }
    public void subtractNRBC()
    {
        num1 = Convert.ToInt32(txtNRBC.Text);
        txtNRBC.Text = Convert.ToString(num1 - 1);//subtract 1
        Total();
    }

public void Total()//totals all textboxes except NRBCs
    {

        total = int.Parse(txtSegs.Text) + int.Parse(txtLymphs.Text) + int.Parse(txtMonos.Text) + int.Parse(txtBands.Text) + int.Parse(txtEos.Text) + int.Parse(txtBasos.Text) + int.Parse(txtMetas.Text)
                    + int.Parse(txtMyelos.Text) + int.Parse(txtPros.Text) + int.Parse(txtBlasts.Text) + int.Parse(txtPlasmas.Text);
        txtTotal.Text = Convert.ToString(total);

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If possible, change your event from `KeyPress` to `KeyDown`. This will allow you to use the `KeyEventArgs` instead of a `KeyPressEventArgs` and solve your problem, as the latter does not seem to recognize the numpad correctly.

Instead of hardcoding your values, you can also use the `Keys` enum. It's cleaner than adding a comment.

```
private void txtTotal_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    switch (e.KeyCode)
    {
        case Keys.NumPad0:
            addNRBC();
            break;
        case Keys.D0:
            subtractNRBC();
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Question, if you use the KeyDown and the user holds the key down, will that loop the execution until the key is released (ie continue to add or subtract until it is released)? If so, can I use the KeyUp instead and not have this happen?

Comment: @DarkPhoenix86 Yes, it will loop. And yes, `KeyUp` will only trigger on the key release, so once. So the right choice depends on what you're trying to achieve. Your input comes from a textbox, so I guess the 0 typed will also be displayed. If a user keeps the 0 pressed, with `KeyUp` he will see multiple 0's in the textbox but only a single `add` will be done (on release). With `KeyDown` he will see multiple 0's displayed and one `add` operation will be performed for each of those 0s.

Comment: Thanks for all the help! The textbox the key is pressed in I changed to a read-only field. So basically I want the user to be able to position the cursor in this read-only txtTotal then be able to press multiple different keys to add or subtract 1 to multiple different textboxes, then this txtTotal will display the total of all those texboxes. I put a case statement for each key that I want used all in the KeyUp event for txtTotal. And I have add and subtract methods(ie addNRBC) for each textbox that needs to be added to or subtracted from. This seems to be working. Thanks again.